# Adobe Flash CS4 frame-switching button not working

Tags: flash, button, cs4

I'm coding a proof-of-concept experiment to myself about buttons switching frames in flash CS4. Whenever i press the button when I run this however, it gives this error message, and I don't know what it means. "ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/NextFrame(). Expected 0, got 1.". Help?

```
stop();
var page = 1;
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, NextFrame);
function NextFrame(){
gotoAndPlay(2);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually means that your `NextFrame()` function expected no arguments but instead it received one.

This happens because you are using `NextFrame()` to listen for events: in AS3, event listener functions receive the event object they are listening for.

I prefer to solve the problem by adding the argument even when I don't use it:

```
function NextFrame(e: Event){
  gotoAndPlay(2);
};
```